# xcode 8 auto layout uiimageview problems

Tags: swift, xcode, layout, uiimageview, storyboard

I have a Android background and now try to code for iOS.

I use Swift as the language and it works really good so far. Now I am getting some troubles to get my layout to work on different screen resolutions that means different iPhones.

I am using storyboards for my ViewController and for now everything worked well except getting `UIImageViews` to look the same on each iPhone.

I tried now for 2 whole days with dozens of different approaches to get my layout work, but without any success. If I place a single `UIImageView` on my layout I am able to set the constraints so that it looks the same on each iPhone. Once I place a `UIImageView` on top of my first `UIImageView` it destroys everything. I won´t tell you here what I already tried, because it was a lot and nothing worked for me.

I need really some hint or just someone who could just try it on his Storyboard and tell me how he achieved it to get it work. I am using Xcode 8.2.1.

This is how it should look like (iPhone 7):

[image: This is how it should look like (iPhone 7)]

This is how it looks on a iPhone 4s --> wrong! Proportions are not the same!

[image: This is how it looks on a iPhone 4s --> wrong! Proportions are not the same!]

Comment: please show your expected result and the current screen that you got after running in simulator or device

Comment: Hi. I already attached two images. The expected result is as the first pic is showing. The second shows how it is on the simulator on an iPhone 4s and nearly as on my real device iPhone 5s. As you can see the proportion between height and width changed and is not correct anymore. The big ImageView orignal 335:230=1.45, the smaller ones 205:210 = 0.97 and two times 100:100 = 1. On the iPhone 4s the proportions getting wrong: 286:165= 1.73 and not 1.45!!! The same happens for the other smaller ImageViews. Thanks

Comment: Are you setting a ratio constraint? Also, what other constraints do you have set? Last question - are you using UIStackViews? If not, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's need more params and maybe UIStackViews.

[image: Big Image View]

[image: The smaller ones]

[image: small 1]

[image: small 2]

https://github.com/OMGHaveFun/exampleAutolayout

Comment: WOW!!! I wasn´t expecting that!! I tried it and it works! It looks very complicated to me and I have to analyze it, because I have two other ViewController with the same problem. Thank you very much! Indeed it seems not to be that easy!